# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, pandas-datareader

I need an advice and I'm new with this stuff. I try to run Yahoo! Finance Fix for Pandas Datareader.py but the result ends up like this which you can see below. Thank you in advance.

runfile('C:/Users/johannesbambang/Desktop/Yahoo! Finance Fix for Pandas Datareader.py', wdir='C:/Users/johannesbambang/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/johannesbambang/Desktop/Yahoo! Finance Fix for Pandas Datareader.py', wdir='C:/Users/johannesbambang/Desktop')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/johannesbambang/Desktop/Yahoo! Finance Fix for Pandas Datareader.py", line 1, in 
    from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 18, in 
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\fred.py", line 1, in 
    from pandas_datareader.compat import is_list_like

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'

For more information, please see this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRcrY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the `pandas_datareader` library. Your error is because of this library's issue and will be fixed in the next release.

As is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887576/4539956), you have to wait until the 0.7.0 version or install the [development version](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install-latest-development-version).