# python cannot import name 'is_list_like'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run the following code using **pandas_datareader** on PYTHON 3.6.5 IDLE(WIN 10 SYS).

```
#import our Python libraries
import os
import sys

import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt     #tsa为Time Series analysis缩写
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as scs
from arch import arch_model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
```

It seems work on IDE eclipse, but when I try to run it on jupyter notebook, although i have installed the **pandas_datareader** package, jupyter continues 
to stop with the following errors. I have checked that it is not concerned with any circular references or any file name conflicts.Why does it happen?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4b149e7cab54> in <module>()
      4 
      5 import pandas as pd
----> 6 import pandas_datareader.data as web
      7 import numpy as np
      8 

d:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from ._version import get_versions
----> 2 from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
      3                    get_dailysummary_iex, get_data_enigma, get_data_famafrench,
      4                    get_data_fred, get_data_google, get_data_moex,
      5                    get_data_morningstar, get_data_quandl, get_data_stooq,

d:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in <module>()
     12     ImmediateDeprecationError
     13 from pandas_datareader.famafrench import FamaFrenchReader
---> 14 from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
     15 from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
     16 from pandas_datareader.google.options import Options as GoogleOptions

d:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\fred.py in <module>()
----> 1 from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
      2 from pandas import concat, read_csv
      3 
      4 from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

Comment: what is your versions of the `pandas` and `pandas-datareader`?

Comment: @BearBrown sorry to reply late, my `pandas` version is 0.22.0 and my `pandas-datareader` version is 0.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of `pandas-datareader` and will be fixed on [release 0.7.0](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/495) as stated [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/534#issuecomment-393707462).

For now, you could try to use the development version based on its master branch.